# Audio Source option in Developer option in Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have recently updated to Android Marshmallow. In developer options, I found a new option "Select USB configuration" having sub options like

- Charging Only
- MTP
- PTP
- RNDIS (USB Ethernet)
- Audio Source
- MIDI

I have used the first three options "Charging only", MTP and PTP. But how does the last 3 options work?

I tried with "Audio Source", and I think this option is intended to use your phone as USB host for audio sourcing, but still I am not able to figure out how it will work?

Answer (score 2):

- Audio source allows your phone's audio output to be routed as a mic input into your computer.
- MIDI will allow your phone to act as a midi device and give midi instructions to your computer. You will need to use midi supported apps to make it work. Something like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobileer.midikeyboard)